# T-SQL Multi-Value Parameter XML Only Executing on First Value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using XML parsing to pass multiple parameter values into a stored procedure.

Code to create the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE[dbo].[test] @PARAM varchar(max)
AS
DECLARE @PARAMXML AS XML
SET @PARAMXML = cast(('<A>'+replace(@PARAM,',' ,'</A><A>')
                 +'</A>') AS XML)
```

Code to call the parameter:

```
WHERE Field IN (SELECT A.value('.','varchar(max)') FROM @PARAMXML.nodes('A') AS FN(A)
```

Code to execute the parameter:

```
exec dbo.test 'Hello, Goodbye, Welcome'
```

This results in only 'Hello' being passed and executed without error. Goodbye and Welcome are not processed. Why is that? I used this example:
https://raresql.com/tag/sql-server-passing-multiple-values-through-one-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the result of the splitting on the comma has leading spaces ([demo](http://rextester.com/LBTAJ9113)) for all except the first word so your string comparison doesn't match.

try it with the spaces removed:

```
 DECLARE @PARAM varchar(max) = 'Hello, Goodbye, Welcome'
DECLARE @PARAMXML AS XML
SET @PARAMXML = cast(('<A>'+replace(@PARAM,',' ,'</A><A>')
                 +'</A>') AS XML)

SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(A.value('.','varchar(max)'))) FROM @PARAMXML.nodes('A') AS FN(A)
```

or alternatively remove the spaces here:

```
SET @PARAMXML = cast(('<A>'+replace(@PARAM,', ' ,'</A><A>')
                 +'</A>') AS XML)
```